# Why doesn't my light beam render?

Tags: rendering

I made a light beam, very similar to this: https://cloud.blender.org/p/caminandes-3/56c6da5cc379cf0079716873, but for some reason I can't render it. If I switch to rendered view mode, I see everything in place, but when I render it, there's nothing in place of the beam, except for some lighter and yellower rain drops.[image]
on the top half, you can see 3d rendered view mode, on the bottom half, you can see actual rendered image. I have checked in outliner, that everything should render (which is also visible from the image).
Here is my nodesetup: [image]
I am using cycles render.

Comment: Please upload your file to get analyzed. Try to uncheck the compositor and the sequencer in the "post processing" render tab.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to connect an emission shader to the volume parameter of the output node, if you want a real light beam then create a spot light and put your scene into a cube with volume absorbtion/shaders.

Comment: @Yvain It works, check this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67309/how-to-create-a-ufo-pickup-light-ray/67336#67336

Comment: ok, but the man doesn't show a rendered picture (only preview) so you better be going with the second solution of the link you posted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely nothing wrong with your setup.

The issue is with the **render viewport not being able to display emissive and transparent pixels**.

To check this try either

- Disabling Film>Transparent
- or compositing your image over some color (or black) background,
- or simply looking at the RGB image with no alpha on the viewer.

  Related: [Transparent Image different in viewport than render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/56986#56986)  - and [How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824)