# Light rays through glass

Tags: modeling, node-editor, light

I try to achieve that my lightrays are going through glass.
With a volumetric container and *without* a glass in front of the light everything works fine.
[image]
But if I make my glass visible the lightrays disappear.

So I searched a little bit and found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67309/how-to-create-a-ufo-pickup-light-ray).
I tried it but with this technic I have the problem that it affects the color of the button light. Additionally I was not able to get the nice fade out effect from the question above.
I think its because my cylinder has a hole and is not filled like in the example.

[image]

So how can I do this without (or at least only a little bit) affecting the lightcolor of my button and with a glass infront of the light of the button?

Is it possible to get the result from the firt picture but with a glass infront of the light source?

Here is my blendfile.[image]

Comment: Can you post a [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: @pycoder yes I updated my question.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/spherical-emitter-does-not-illuminate-very-well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glass shader by itself won't let light pass through it the way you want. 
You need to modify the material by adding some transparency controlled with a light path node.

For more detail please read: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

The volumetric light you can do just by adding some volume scattering to the world.
[image]

*click on the image to enlarge*

Comment: Yes this is what I needed! Thank you. Why do you use additionally to the glass node a transparency node?

Comment: Please read the link on the answer.