# How to properly make certain areas of a mesh transparent

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner in Blender and seeking advice how to properly make certain areas of a mesh transparent.

I have a house, which is built out of a cube. In Edit mode I've added planes to represent windows.
These planes have material glass.

I would like to put a light source inside the house, however, as the material of the house is not transparent, the light does not come through the windows.

I tried to cut areas of the house where the windows are through loop cut and subdivide, but as the windows have irregular shapes, it requires ages to cut and introduces too many polygons.

I wonder if there is any better way to make sure that the areas of a mesh, where planes are located are cut out in order to be able to see light through them.[image: the house in question]

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal Render or Cycles? You should use the "edit" button under you original post and add it there.

Comment: By default the glass shader doesn't let light trough, you need to change it as described on these answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/light-rays-through-glass/68426#68426 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Those doors and windows seem to be overlayed faces atop of the walls. In that case even if you assign fully transparent material nothing will be visible, wall material will interfere with them. Model walls so they have faces cut in them which can be (for simplicity) deleted and leave a hole in the wall, then you know it really allows light to go through