# Emission glow through glass materrial

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, light, volumetrics, emission

How to create a emission material that will glow through glass material in Cycles render? (volumetric light)

I have attached the project file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NreO9LvHx41nt_uOUxasqxgS9RXASLzr/view?usp=sharing

I do not want to be in Eevee, also without Compositing effects;
thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: you can't make it glow like the Eevee bloom effect unless you do it through the Compositor. Or you have a trick like using Layer Weight

Comment: What have you already tried? What specific part are you stuck with? Please be more specific.

Comment: It looks like you already have an emissive material (the blue) - just turn up the emission strength.

Comment: If you don't want to use the compositor (why?), then you need to create volumetrics. Glow is either a post production effect, or is created by light scattered in a volume (like smoke, mist,  etc.) Either create a mesh that surrounds your object and use volume scatter on it, or add volume scatter to the world. Read: [volumetric lighting not showing very well](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111146)  And the glass material needs to be modified to let direct light through. Read: [light rays through glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/light-rays-through-glass)