# How make glow in Compositing if emission is behind glass?

Tags: light, compositing-nodes, glass

Why I can't make glow in Compositing in Cycles if emission is behind glass?
If use Glare, everything in picture will be glow, but I don't need it. I need only certain parts to glow, for example, like here - bulbs in headlights.

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do this in compositing? isn't it easier to create an emission for the bulb lights and turn "bloom" on?

Comment: @Chris, Bloom is for Eevee, not Cycles, it looks like he's working with 2.79

Comment: thanks, but yes i know, and how should i know he uses Cycles?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to do this exactly in Cycles.

Comment: @Chris, Eevee was not in 2.7, at least it was not installed by default

Comment: thanks, did not know that ;)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/light-rays-through-glass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a trick because alpha is not use for glass transparency so you can't isolate the glass object.

You can fix it in the **Compositor** with this trick:

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttKA8AjxYzM) Jordan Sautron explains how to give an effect to an *Emission* object behind a glass. It's in french so I try to summarize.

- Give a *Pass Index* to your emission material (*Properties > Material > Viewport Display > Settings*), for example give 1.
- In *Properties > View Layers > Passes > Data*, activate *Indexes > Material Indexes*.
- In the *Compositor*, create a *Render Layer* with the glass, a second one without.
- Create a *Converter > ID Mask* node in front of the second *Render Layer* node, type the material index of the emitter material (1).
- Create a *Color > Mix* node (*Multiply* mode). Plug the first *Render Layer* node in the first socket, plug the *ID Mask* in the second socket.
- Plug the *Mix* into a *Filter > Glare* node, put its Mix value at 1.
- Plug the *Glare* into the second socket of a *Color > Mix* node / *Add* mode. Plug the first *Render Layer* in its first socket, put its factor at 1 or more.

[image]

Another solution is to fake the glow effect with the **Layer Weight** node: Create a sphere around your light object and give it a mix of *Emission* and *Transparent* nodes, with a *Layer Weight* as factor:

[image]

Of course you can make it a bit more complicated with some noise etc:

[image]

You can even give it a *Displacement* node. In that case don't forget to go into the *Properties panel > Material > Settings > Displacement > Displacement Only*:

[image]

Comment: This is useful tutorial. And thanks for translation from french. Only using different layers is not very convenient. Rendering almost the same picture 2 times is long, especially for animations. But I suppose that can transfer objects with Emission to another layer & render it instead of the whole picture without glass. It will be much faster this way & I think result will be the same.

Comment: if you don't care about too much realism you have tricks to create this kind of effects like for example create a sphere with transparency and emission mixed into a mix shader with a layer weight as factor, please tell me if you want me to show you

Comment: Yes please, show me what you mean if possible.

Comment: ok I've edited, I'll show what it gives with a bit of noise...

Comment: It looks impressive. I think I'll find application for this. Thanks for all.

Comment: This (first) solution will not take into account deformation of light created by the glass right? For instance if you are trying to make this picture glow, you would glow along the original picture right?

Comment: hello, it's a long time ago, I guess you're right

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to blur, use a [**glare** node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/glare.html?highlight=glare). It will give you finer control since the effect is based on a threshold, to effect the picture based on the brightness of the pixels.

[image]

Read:

[Any way to control light halos in the compositor based on emission level?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54168/any-way-to-control-light-halos-in-the-compositor-based-on-emission-level/54173#54173)

Also, **the default glass shader will not work correctly for a light that is behind glass**.

Try something like this:

[image]

Read: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles/2565#2565)

---

If you must use glow, you can use a pass index to determine what gets blurred.

[image]

For complete instructions on how to set this up read:

[One part of the render layer glowing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation of how Glare node works. But ID mask for Glare also doesn't work if Emission is behind Glass. I need to use ID mask to set strength, shape & glow for each light bulb separately. Simply using Glare won't give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If your emission has a very specific color which is not found elsewhere in the picture, you can also easily solve it by just chroma-keying/color-keying it to get your original mask:

[image]

(Here I use several "glare" masks to have a stronger effect, but I guess you could use a Gaussian or any other kind of glare)