# Cycles & Blender Render for God Beams / Crepuscular Rays / Sun Beams

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, light, compositing-nodes, volumetrics

I'm having trouble getting the actual beam of light to show in the render of my image. What I want to do is create an image that looks like this:
[image]

However, In blender render I am unable to get the walls to show any color:
[image]

And with Cycles render the walls and other objects become clear but there are no lines of the sunbeam:
[image]

I have been attempting to follow other guides such as:
[Creating volumetric lighting (crepuscular rays) in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/creating-volumetric-lighting-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles)
[How to make sunbeams in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/how-to-make-sunbeams-in-blender?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Correct way to render crepuscular rays in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/correct-way-to-render-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles)
[Correct way to render crepuscular rays in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/correct-way-to-render-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles)
To no avail. Even using Compositing nodes seems to have little effect. Does anyone have any tips or notice any flaws in the blender file I'm working on? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Blender file: [image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67309/how-to-create-a-ufo-pickup-light-ray

Comment: Gleb has some [text](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/lighting-tutorial-atmospheric-effects-dust-book-10.html) or [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXjE-t6dFZ8) tips, or you may prefer the slower paced [blender guru](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-atmospheric-lighting-blender/)