# Create a energy beam

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have the following objects. The cage of the lamp is one object, and the dome is the other. How would I go about having the dome emit a beam of energy or light? I am using Cycles Render[image]
Clarification: like the beacon in wreck-it-ralph[image]

Comment: Which renderer are you using: Internal, Cycles, Lux etc?

Comment: Using Cycles render

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67309/how-to-create-a-ufo-pickup-light-ray/67336#67336

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to mess with this to get it to work.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://youtu.be/PXGFNdvLyBU https://youtu.be/S6lSfOfiXHY?t=3172

Answer (score 1):

If you want it simple you could use a cylinder with an emission shader to it. With compositing you could apply a glare node.

Comment: Emission node into volumetric material output node. Use a texture to drive intensity if you want texture and flickering.